# Can not run Redhawk SDR 1.9 on RHel 6.5 64 bit because of ombiORBpy 32 bit .so files

Tags: redhawksdr

When I run the basic example from the Redhawk site I get the error:
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_omnipymodule.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

I am trying to run Redhawk SDR 1.9 on RHel 6.5 64 bit computer.  I download the CentOS 6 rpms from the redhawk-deps-yum-el6-i686.tar.gz.  When I install the files, it installs some RPMs that are i386 and they do indeed contain 32 bit ELF .so libraries.  I had the Red Hat Compatibility libraries installed (I double checked that) but I am still getting the error.

I also went to the omniORB page and downloaded the omniORBpy3.6 release and tried to build a 64 bit version but it did not work.

Does anyone know if there are RHel 6.5 64-bit versions of the libomniORBpy RPMs?

This is also causing the code in the Redhawk IDE to not be able to generate All Implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the filename you posted, you downloaded the 32-bit files (that's the i686 in your filename). Double-check which link you're following. Download links are here: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/download.html